# DTD not found error while updating attribute value using Ant XmlTask

Tags: xml, ant, dtd, xmltask, xmlcatalog

I want to update value of `debug.classpath` property. I am using `XmlTask` to do manipulations. However, I am running to `DTD` not found issue.

This is my target XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configuration SYSTEM "xconf.dtd">
<Configuration>
     <Property name="debug.classpath" value="<changeme>"
</Configuration>
```

This is my Ant target.

```
<target name="configure" >
      <xmltask source="myxml.xml">
            <attr path="//Property[@name='debug.classpath']" attr="value"  value="New Value"/>
      </xmltask>    
</target>
```

When I execute this target, I get below error.

> [xmltask] java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\utils\xconf.dtd (The
>   system cannot find the file specified)

This DTD is present in a Jar file called `Utils.jar`. After google'ing I found `XmlCatalog` task and using that I wrote below version of my target.(Not sure if I've made intended use of `XmlCatalog`). The `Utils.jar` is not in Ant's classpath hence tried to add it using `<classpath>`.

```
<target name="configure">
    <xmlcatalog id="XconfDtd">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="D:/libs/Utils.jar"/>
        </classpath>
        <dtd location="xconf.dtd" />
    </xmlcatalog>
    <xmltask source="${env.WT_HOME}/codebase/wt.properties.xconf">
        <xmlcatalog refid="XconfDtd" />
        <attr path="//Property[@name='debug.classpath']" attr="value" value="New Value" />
    </xmltask>
</target>
```

However, when I execute this target, I get below error

> [xmltask] java.lang.NullPointerException  [xmltask]     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.XMLCatalog.findMatchingEntry(XMLCatalog.java:592)
>   [xmltask]     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.XMLCatalog.access$000(XMLCatalog.java:119) 
>   [xmltask]     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.XMLCatalog$InternalResolver.resolveEntity(XMLCatalog.java:811)
>   [xmltask]     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.types.XMLCatalog.resolveEntity(XMLCatalog.java:385)
>   [xmltask]     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(EntityResolverWrapper.java:110)
>   [xmltask]     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntityAsPerStax(XMLEntityManager.java:994)
>   [xmltask]     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1149)
>   [xmltask]     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1047)
>   [xmltask]     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:960)
>   [xmltask]     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
>   [xmltask]     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
>   [xmltask]     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
>   [xmltask]     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
>   [xmltask]     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)

Even after putting `Utils.jar` to `$ANT_HOME/lib` I still see above error. Any help is highly appreciated. You can suggest any alternate way to achieve this in Ant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `locatio` in `<pathelement locatio="D:/libs/Utils.jar"/>` just a typo? (Should be `location`.)

Comment: I think it will work it you simply remove the doctype declaration (`<!DOCTYPE Configuration SYSTEM "xconf.dtd">`). Do you have to keep it in the XML file?

Comment: @mzjn Yes. I want to keep it in the file.

Comment: OK. How about extracting xconf.dtd from the JAR file and and putting it in the same directory as the XML file?

Comment: @mzjn: That way it works. But it is not feasible for me to do this. Hence I want XmlTask to reference it from the Jar itself.